# May adding a route to a machine makes it reachable from the outside?

Tags: networking

The guys from my network team have problems making one of our new server
accessible from the outside.

For some reason they require us to have our servers in a vlan on
192.168.222.0/24 and they NAT them so that they are reachable from the 
outside.  This is a many years old scheme that is generally not 
problematic.

Yet we presently have a problem with one out of 2 new servers - let's
call it servA. This one can reach any network we want (or are allowed
to), but it cannot be reached except from 192.168.222.0/24.

There is some fun in the fact that his sister-server (let's call her 
servB) who as been built in parallel is perfectly OK, the NAT is working
(as for many many other servers). Since we mostly have an automated
deployement method, the only differences between servA and servB are the 
IP adresses put in their /etc/network/interfaces (those are Debian
boxes).

I try interverting the jacks on the switch both machines are connected
to with no success (i.e. servB keep OK, servA still not reachable) so
this seems to put a problem on the port configuration aside.

I finally shut down servB and started servA with servB IP address and 
behold : it works !

I told the guys from the network that in my opinion this clearly showed
that there was some problem on their equipment, but they insist on
making me test this or that on servA. They just asked me to add some
route to the route table of servA. Since I have no choice I did this but 
with no avail, as I expected. I'm currently expecting their answer regarding this test.

Given this, here are my questions to you network gurus :

1. is it possible that the problem is really on servA ?
2. is it possible that this problem might be solved by just adding a
   route to servA?

As far as I understand what adding a route means, this
might help servA to reach some host or network, but should have no
impact on servA being reached from the outside; am I right here ?

Thanks in advance,

phep

Answer (score 1):

1. The problem is likely not on server A. Since changing the switchports didn't give you any success, it's probably not the switchport - especially since with server B's original IP address you could connect on your original switchport with server A.
2. Sounds more like a NAT/firewall issue than anything, so I'm not sure what adding a route would do - unless this route exists on server B and not on server A. Since server A's okay as is using server B's IP address, route addition seems a strange troubleshooting path to follow.
   Since this is a NAT environment, you're basically correct on your assumption about traffic coming in from the outside - unless egress and ingress traffic has different points of entry and exit.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it works if you change the IP indicate that the issue is most likely on the network guys side.

As for the route, any networking communication is bi-directional : request / answer. But the server is unaware of which path the request took, and it sends the answer according to its own routing table.

That means if a machine contact server A (I.E. server A bing reached from the outside), the server A must now where to send the response. So adding a route may in some specific case help.

From what you describe I doubt this is a route issue on server A in your case.

Did the network guys ask for the routing table of server A or to perform a traceroute ?

Comment: They first asked me to produce the routing table of both servers (that are exactly the same, as expected - minus their own IP address I mean). After that they asked me to add a route to servA table but the `route add ... `  command failed with a `SIOCADDRT network not reachable`. They told me this route was _not clean_, anyway. Since my previous message they only asked me to remember them of servB address. Thanks anyway @JFL for your explanations about the sort-of round-trip process implying the server route.